# Segmentation fault with structures assignments C

Tags: c

I get segmentation fault on `v[cant]=completar();`
I checked the function completar and it works ok, and the `segmentation fault` only appears if I do the assignment. So I really don't know what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define cant 100
#define nom  20
struct detalles
{
    int l;
    char n[nom];
    float p;
    int I;
};

struct detalles completar();
main()
{ 
    int i;
    struct detalles v[cant];


    //trouble is here

    v[cant]=completar();

    for(i=0;i<(v[0].I);i++)
    {
        printf("\v\v\v\v\v\r");
        printf("legajo\t%d\n",v[i].l);
        printf("Nombre\t%s\n",v[i].n);
        printf("Promedio\t%f\n",v[i].p);
    }
    return 0;
}

struct detalles completar()
{

    int i=0;
    struct detalles temp[cant];
    printf("Ingrese cero cundo desee terminar\n");
    do
    {
        printf("Ingrese el numero de legajo de un estudiante\t");
        scanf("%d",&temp[i].l);
        while(temp[i].l<0)
        {
            printf("El numero ingresado no es valido, intente nuevamente\v\v\r");
            printf("Ingrese el numero de legajo de un estudiante\t");
            scanf("%d",&temp[i].l);
        }
        printf("ingrese el nombre del alumno\t");
        scanf("%s",temp[i].n);
        printf("Ingrese promedio del alumno\t");
        scanf("%f",&temp[i].p);
        i++;
        if(i==100)
        {
            printf("Se ha superado en numero maximo de estudiantes\n");
        }
    }
    while((temp[i-1].p!=0)&&(temp[i-1].l!=0)&&(i<100));
    temp[0].I=i-1;
    return temp[cant];
}
```

Comment: Your program invokes *undefined behavior*. You're accessing your `v` array out of range. It is only `cant` items in size, meaning it is only subscriptable by `0..(cant-1)`. Further `v[0].I` is *indeterminate*, yet you rely on its value in the condition of your `for(i-0;i<v[0].I;...) loop.; more undefined behavior.

Comment: not sure if this is _the_ problem, but you are writing outside the bounds ofr your `v` array. Indices should be from 0 to `cant - 1`

Comment: `return temp[cant];` has the same problem.  It doesn't refer to the whole array, it refers to an invalid position one past the end of the array.

Comment: They are. Look the while, it don't get to 100.

Comment: it doesn't matter what the `while` loop is doing. `cant` is a defined constant. `return temp[cant];` is the same as `return temp[100];`, which is outside the bounds of the array. If you want to return the last element in the array, `return temp[cant-1];` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`cant` is equal to 100, you assign a value to `v[cant]`, that is to `v[100]`, but the array `v`, with length `100`, is assignable only with an index from `0` to `99`.

Comment: I don't use index 100. Only on the while below I use the index and don't include the 100. Anyway, If I comment the line v[cant]=completar(); it works fine. So don't why there's a trouble if the function returners temp[cant].

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
while((temp[i-1].p!=0)&&(temp[i-1].l!=0)&&(i<100));
    temp[0].I=i-1;
    return temp[cant];

Comment: @rocbl, the first command of the `main` is `v[cant]=completar();`, and `cant` is a constant with value 100, so the statement is actually assigning a value returned by `completar()` to `v[100]`. This is the reason of the segmentation, as you have discovered by commenting that line. The statement `return temp[cant];` does not cause the fault since you are only reading `v[100]`, not assigning it, but this means that the statement read a value outside of the vector space.